# React, Typescript Error: How can I solve type error? (HTMLButtonElement problem)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Greeting!

I make TodoList Sample, Use by React, Redux, Typescript, SCSS.

I have one problem about Typescript error.

### Here is error status.

```
Type '(event: { target: HTMLButtonElement; }) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type '{ target: HTMLButtonElement; }'.
      Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
        Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLButtonElement': disabled, form, formAction, formEnctype, and 248 more.
```

I made TodoItem remove function.

So This is my code.

### Container (Add onClickRemoveTodo)

#### TodosContainer

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import TodoAdd from 'src/components/todo/TodoAdd';
import TodoList from 'src/components/todo/TodoList';
import { RootState } from 'src/redux/rootReducer';
import { changeTodo, clearTodo } from 'src/redux/todo/todo';
import { removeTodo, setAddNewTodo } from 'src/redux/todo/todos';

const TodosContainer = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { todo, todos } = useSelector((state: RootState) => ({
    todo: state.todo,
    todos: state.todos,
  }));

  const onChangeTodoAdd = (event: { target: HTMLInputElement }) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    dispatch(changeTodo({ name, value }));
  };

  const onClickTodoAdd = () => {
    dispatch(setAddNewTodo({ todo }));
    dispatch(clearTodo());
  };

  // I made onClickRemoveTodo
  const onClickRemoveTodo = (event: { target: HTMLButtonElement }) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    dispatch(removeTodo({ id: parseInt(value, 10) }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h3>TodosContainer</h3>
      <TodoAdd
        todo={todo}
        onChange={onChangeTodoAdd}
        onClick={onClickTodoAdd}
      />
      {/* // Pass to TodoList (onClickRemoveTodo -> onRemove) */}
      <TodoList
        todos={todos}
        onRemove={onClickRemoveTodo}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default TodosContainer;
```

### Components (Add onRemove)

#### TodoList

```
import React from 'react';

import { Todo } from 'src/types/todo';
import { isEmpty } from 'src/utils/tools';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

export type TodoListProps = {
  todos: Todo[];
  onRemove: (event: { target: HTMLButtonElement }) => void;
};

const TodoList = ({ todos, onRemove }: TodoListProps) => {
  if (isEmpty(todos.length)) {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Todo List Empty</p>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h4>TodoList</h4>
      {
        todos.map(({ id, content }) => (
          // Pass to TodoItem (onRemove -> onRemove)
          <TodoItem
            key={id}
            id={id}
            content={content}
            onRemove={onRemove}
          />
        ))
      }
    </>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

#### TodoItem

```
import React from 'react';

import { isEmpty } from 'src/utils/tools';

export type TodoItemProps = {
  id: number;
  content: string;
  // I think this is problem.
  onRemove: (event: { target: HTMLButtonElement }) => void;
};

const TodoItem = ({ id, content, onRemove }: TodoItemProps) => {
  if (isEmpty(id)) {
    return (
      <></>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>{content}</p>
      <button
        type="button"
        // FIXME: need to solve Typesript error case, but logic work well.
        onClick={onRemove}
        value={id}
      >
        remove
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default TodoItem;
```

So i made onClickRemoveTodo function from TodosContainer and it pass TodosContainer -> TodoList -> TodoItem.
Also Logic has no problem. It works(remove Todo) in webpage.
But suddenly TodoItem Component / onClick={onRemove} show type error.
I try to find solution, but i had no clue this.

Here is my repository and you can read detail code.

https://github.com/DavidYang2149/react_redux_typescript_scss_starter

Thank you for reading this. :)

===========================================================================

### Solved

### Container (Add onClickRemoveTodo)

#### TodosContainer

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import TodoAdd from 'src/components/todo/TodoAdd';
import TodoList from 'src/components/todo/TodoList';
import { RootState } from 'src/redux/rootReducer';
import { changeTodo, clearTodo } from 'src/redux/todo/todo';
import { removeTodo, setAddNewTodo } from 'src/redux/todo/todos';

const TodosContainer = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { todo, todos } = useSelector((state: RootState) => ({
    todo: state.todo,
    todos: state.todos,
  }));

  const onChangeTodoAdd = (event: { target: HTMLInputElement }) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    dispatch(changeTodo({ name, value }));
  };

  const onClickTodoAdd = () => {
    dispatch(setAddNewTodo({ todo }));
    dispatch(clearTodo());
  };

  // Fixed :)
  const onClickRemoveTodo = ({ id }: { id: number }) => {
    dispatch(removeTodo({ id }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h3>TodosContainer</h3>
      <TodoAdd
        todo={todo}
        onChange={onChangeTodoAdd}
        onClick={onClickTodoAdd}
      />
      <TodoList
        todos={todos}
        onRemove={onClickRemoveTodo}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default TodosContainer;
```

### Components (Add onRemove)

#### TodoList

```
import React from 'react';

import { Todo } from 'src/types/todo';
import { isEmpty } from 'src/utils/tools';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

export type TodoListProps = {
  todos: Todo[];
  // Fixed :)
  onRemove: ({ id }: { id: number }) => void;
};

const TodoList = ({ todos, onRemove }: TodoListProps) => {
  if (isEmpty(todos.length)) {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Todo List Empty</p>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h4>TodoList</h4>
      {
        todos.map(({ id, content }) => (
          <TodoItem
            key={id}
            id={id}
            content={content}
            onRemove={onRemove}
          />
        ))
      }
    </>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

#### TodoItem

```
import React from 'react';

import { isEmpty } from 'src/utils/tools';

export type TodoItemProps = {
  id: number;
  content: string;
  // Fixed :)
  onRemove: ({ id }: { id: number }) => void;
};

const TodoItem = ({ id, content, onRemove }: TodoItemProps) => {
  if (isEmpty(id)) {
    return (
      <></>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>{content}</p>
      <button
        type="button"
        // Fixed :)
        onClick={() => onRemove({ id })}
      >
        remove
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default TodoItem;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change all your definition of onRemove to MouseEventHandler.

```
import { MouseEventHandler } from 'react';
onRemove: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
```

For onclick function

```
import { MouseEvent } from 'react';
const onClickRemoveTodo = (event: MouseEvent) => {//you code...}
```

Comment: thank you for answer to me! :) 
I just try that way. TodoItemProps, TodoListProps work.
But when TodosContainer 
<TodoList
        todos={todos}
        // This is new Type error
        onRemove={onClickRemoveTodo}
/>

So i think onClickRemoveTodo also change definition...

const onClickRemoveTodo = (event: { target: HTMLButtonElement }) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    dispatch(removeTodo({ id: parseInt(value, 10) }));
  };

is there any i can do this...?
thank you.

Comment: My bad, I thought you can deduce from there. I edited my answer, added more detail. @DavidYang

Comment: By the way, button has no value prop defined, so if you continue this path, you get alot trouble with types.

Comment: A better way to use the onclick function is <button onclick={()=>onRemove(id)}>. then your define your onRemove function type.

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed problem. @Shen